# ArcObjects - Geometry type select with Vbnet

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, geometry, vb.net

How can I read the geometry type of shapefiles with ArcObjects and Vbnet?

I want to check whether it is a point, polygon, or a line.

Answer (score 1):

include ESRI.ArcGIS.DatabaseSourcesFile in your project
here is a C# code showes you how to open a shape file,you can convert it to VB.Net simply

```
IWorkspaceFactory ipShapeWF = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass();
`//strfilepath the path to shape file,include only folder not shape file itself'
IWorkspace ipShapeWS = ipShapeWF.OpenFromFile(strfilepath, 0);

IFeatureWorkspace ipFW = (IFeatureWorkspace)ipShapeWS;

IFeatureClass ipFC = ipFW.OpenFeatureClass("shapefilename");

MessageBox.Show(ipFC.ShapeType.ToString());
```